# Page Length in DataTable not working when adding date formatting

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatable, datatables

I've been working with datatables and I've been stuck on a fairly simple thing. I've tried a bunch of different solutions online but nothing seemed to work for me.

Basically, I have this table which I've split across multiple pages (25 rows per page).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tableID').DataTable({
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "bInfo": false,
      "searching": false,
      "pagingType": "numbers", 
      "pageLength": 25
    });
    $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
  });
```

However, I noticed that my column with the dates are not sorted properly, as they are being interpreted as strings rather than dates. To fix this, I added this line to the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss');
    $('#tableID').DataTable({
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "bInfo": false,
      "searching": false,
      "pagingType": "numbers", 
      "pageLength": 25
      /*order: false*/
    });
    $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
  });
```

Now the dates are being interpreted as date/sorting properly, but it prints out the entire table on one page. The page length does not seem to work when I add the **$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss');** line, but it works without it. Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

Errors from the console:
[image]

Comment: Did you include the two [required libraries](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18#Operation) needed to support `$.fn.dataTable.moment()`?

Comment: Also, please take a look at the browser console (typically accessed via F12), and then [edit] your question to show us any console error messages.

Comment: @andrewjames Yup, I did import those libraries. I added a picture of the console on the question.

Comment: Update: I was able to fix it. I ended up getting rid of the $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss'); line and added the column def attribute for my table:  "columnDefs" : [{"targets":0, "type":"date"}]

Comment: Glad you have a solution - but for what it's worth, your error tells me that one or both of those extra libraries was not added correctly: maybe an incorrect URL, or placed in the wrong location, or something else. I notice that the documentation omits the `https:` protocol from those resource URLs - so for example, it should be `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js`. Not sure if that makes a difference, but wanted to mention it.

Comment: Minor note for the future: Please provide error messages as formatted text, not as screenshots.